# How to customize wp-bootstrap-navwalker in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use wp-bootstrap-navwalker to customize my navigation.

here is the example of my current static code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav nav navbar-right">
    <li><a class="menu" href="index-2.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">travel</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">lifestyle</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="about.html">about me</a></li>
    <li><a class="last-menu" href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using this wp-bootstrap-navwalker to make it dynamic

```
 wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'primary',
    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
    'depth'             =>  2,
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
);
```

Which is working perfectly fine. Now i have a problem, That i have `menu` class inside my `<a class="menu">home</a>`. How can i put `menu` class inside my anchor tag if that data is coming dynamically. Is there any way that we can customize this `wp_nav_menu(array( ));` ?

Comment: Is `wp_bootstrap_navwalker()` overriding the `start_el` method?

Answer (score 2):

The wordpress way would be to add `'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',` to `wp_nav_menu(array( ))` then you will have special class for custom nav items and normal links items. Then you can target them from CSS.
Usefull link: [wp_nav_items css](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes)

Otherwise you need to change: `wp_bootstrap_navwalker`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
        'depth'             => 2,
        'container'         => 'ul',
        'container_class'   => 'nav-menu',
      //  'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'        => 'nav-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows',
        'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
        'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker()
    ) );
    ?>






<ul class="nav-menu">
                      <li  class="menu-has-children"><a href="about.html">Ба довталаб</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="course-details.html">Course Details</a></li>       
                            <li><a href="event-details.html">Event Details</a></li>     
                            <li><a href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                              <li class="menu-has-children"><a href="">Level 2 </a>
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </li>                                         
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php

Search for: $classes[] = ‘nav-item’;
(Line 146)
Underneath add:
$classes[] = ‘menu’;

Save File & refresh Wordpress

No need to edit functions.php file, changes implemented directly to navwalker php file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

i'm use this code

```
 <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Top navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

and i use this wp-bootstrap-navwalker to make it dynamic

```
 <?php
  wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'top',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'navbarCollapse',
            'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );

  ?>
```

but it never displayed in the exemple showed in getbootstrap